# 'tf' is not defined on load_model() - using lambda

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, keras

I have a `Keras` model that I am trying to export and use in a different python code.

Here is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, GRU, Flatten, Dropout, Lambda
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
import tensorflow as tf


EMBEDDING_DIM = 100

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_length, trainable=False))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)))
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_pad, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=25, validation_data=(X_val_pad, y_val), verbose=2)
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

---

In **another file**, when I import `my_model.h5` :

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Lambda
import tensorflow as tf


def learning(test_samples):
    model = load_model('my_model.h5')
    #ERROR HERE
    #rest of the code
```

The error is the following:

```
  in <lambda>
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)))
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

After research, I got that the fact that **I used `lambda` in my model** is the reason for this problem, but I added these references and it didn't help:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Lambda
import tensorflow as tf
```

What could be the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When loading the model, you need to [explicitly handle custom objects or custom layers](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#handling-custom-layers-or-other-custom-objects-in-saved-models) (CTRL+f the docs for *Handling custom layers*):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5', custom_objects={'tf': tf})
```

Comment: why does ```tf``` considered as custom object? it's just the alias for the library?

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not sure why. Also not sure whether this is still needed with the latest versions of Keras.

Comment: It is needed in tensorflow version 2.1 for sure.

Comment: this worked for me. interestingly I did not have to specify 'tf' as a custom object when the load function was called in the same folder as the corresponding save function. Once I moved my load-call to another folder I had do specify it. This sure looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This being considered a custom object is a very troubling degree of brokenness in keras. Ostensibly the entire benefit of keras migrating under tf.keras is to explicitly avoid this type of problem.

Comment: As of tensorflow 2.5 the behavior still exists. Thanks so much for the workaround- this saved me!

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me too. You need to import tensorflow inside your lambda function. So you probably want to put the code in a separate function:

```
def reduce_mean(x):
    import tensorflow as tf
    return tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_length, trainable=False))
model.add(Lambda(reduce_mean))
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_pad, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=25, validation_data=(X_val_pad, y_val), verbose=2)
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Comment: worked like a charm! And helpful since I couldn't easily modify the load function.

Comment: I still trying to understand how this thing will help me to add my custom function that passed to the Lambda layer without mentioning it in the `tf.keras.models.load_model()` custom objects' parameter??!!

Comment: @Dr.Xavier, you will still need to declare it in the `load_model` function. The problem is that without declaring `import tensorflow` you have no acess to module functions (although I found some other solutions elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Besides, when you try to load the model structure from a json file, passing custom objects solves the problem.

```
model = model_from_json(open("model_structure.json", "r").read(), custom_objects={'tf': tf})
```

Answer (score 0):

One weird solution that has worked for me is to import the module used to create the model.  So say you have file you use to create a model and save it.

**make_model.py**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, GRU, Flatten, Dropout, Lambda
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
import tensorflow as tf


EMBEDDING_DIM = 100

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_length, trainable=False))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)))
...
model.fit(X_train_pad, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=25, validation_data=(X_val_pad, y_val), verbose=2)
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

If you load the model in another file **load_model.py**, you may be able to get around the error via **import** of the first module.

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Lambda
import tensorflow as tf

import make_model

def learning(test_samples):
    model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

This worked for me since the error read

```
UserWarning: make_model is not loaded, but a Lambda layer uses it. It may cause errors.
...
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well - however problem was that the code was refactored and the `Lambda` layer was replaced by something else. In this case, you can always rollback to the point where it worked.

The simple workaround in case you are not able to restore the previous solution is adding: `custom_objects={'tf': tf}` to `restore_model` call